# Keras - How to perform a prediction using KerasRegressor?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network, regression, keras

I am new to machine learning, and I am trying to handle Keras to perform regression tasks. I have implemented this code, based on [this](http://machinelearningmastery.com/regression-tutorial-keras-deep-learning-library-python/) example.

```
X = df[['full_sq','floor','build_year','num_room','sub_area_2','sub_area_3','state_2.0','state_3.0','state_4.0']]
y = df['price_doc']

X = np.asarray(X)
y = np.asarray(y)

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=.2)
def baseline_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(13, input_dim=9, kernel_initializer='normal', 
        activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal'))
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
    return model

estimator = KerasRegressor(build_fn=baseline_model, nb_epoch=100, batch_size=100, verbose=False)
kfold = KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=seed)
results = cross_val_score(estimator, X_train, Y_train, cv=kfold)
print("Results: %.2f (%.2f) MSE" % (results.mean(), results.std()))

prediction = estimator.predict(X_test)
accuracy_score(Y_test, prediction)
```

When I run the code I get this error:

> `AttributeError: 'KerasRegressor' object has no attribute 'model'`

How could I correctly 'insert' the model in KerasRegressor?

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: where are you _fitting_ the estimator?

Comment: @AbhishekThakur `cross_val_score` fits and score the estimator.

Comment: @VivekKumar yes it does but to `predict` on another data, he needs to `fit` the model again. for this line `prediction = estimator.predict(X_test)`

Comment: @Vivek I have added the remaining code. Is it correct `prediction = estimator.predict(X_test)` ?

Comment: @Simone please check the answer.

Comment: @AbhishekThakur Aah yes. I overlooked that detail. My bad.

Comment: @Simone Please add the full stack trace of error, so that we get to know in which line this error is occurring. Until then we are unable to help.

Comment: Actually what version of keras and scikit-learn are you using?

Comment: I have just installed Keras and Scikit-learn, I have the most recent versions

Answer (score 26, accepted):

you have to fit the estimator again after `cross_val_score` to evaluate on the new data:

```
estimator = KerasRegressor(build_fn=baseline_model, nb_epoch=100, batch_size=100, verbose=False)
kfold = KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=seed)
results = cross_val_score(estimator, X_train, Y_train, cv=kfold)
print("Results: %.2f (%.2f) MSE" % (results.mean(), results.std()))

estimator.fit(X, y)
prediction = estimator.predict(X_test)
accuracy_score(Y_test, prediction)
```

Working Test version:

```
from sklearn import datasets, linear_model
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score, KFold
from keras.models import Sequential
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor
seed = 1

diabetes = datasets.load_diabetes()
X = diabetes.data[:150]
y = diabetes.target[:150]

def baseline_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(10, input_dim=10, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
    return model


estimator = KerasRegressor(build_fn=baseline_model, nb_epoch=100, batch_size=100, verbose=False)
kfold = KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=seed)
results = cross_val_score(estimator, X, y, cv=kfold)
print("Results: %.2f (%.2f) MSE" % (results.mean(), results.std()))

estimator.fit(X, y)
prediction = estimator.predict(X)
accuracy_score(y, prediction)
```

Comment: I have tried this solution before, but I get the same result: `AttributeError: 'KerasRegressor' object has no attribute 'model'`

Comment: do you have this line: `estimator.fit(X, y)` ?

Comment: Yes, I have added this line just above `prediction = estimator.predict(X_test)`

Comment: I have also added a working test version that you can just run and check. Can you please post the full stack trace of the error so that we know where the error is?

Comment: The `accuracy_score()` will not be valid for regression task.

Comment: Sure it wont, I just kept it there to keep it similar to OP's question. :)

Comment: @Vivek I have just restarted the kernel, and now Abhisek's solution seems working. What could I use instead of `accuracy_score()`?

Comment: ``
Regression ‘neg_mean_absolute_error’ metrics.mean_absolute_error  
‘neg_mean_squared_error’ metrics.mean_squared_error  
‘neg_median_absolute_error’ metrics.median_absolute_error  
‘r2’ metrics.r2_score``

Comment: @Simone if the answer solved your problem, please consider it accepting.

Comment: @AbhishekThakur  Could you help me in finding a suitable option for substitute `accuracy_score()`?

Comment: @ Abhishek Thakur, I don't quite understand why estimator.fit(X,y) is needed after the training, do this command train the model another time or what? Thanks!

Comment: @AbhishekThakur the estimator.fit(X, y) should be called on the x_train and y_train ? otherwise, the estimator.predict(X) will use the X as data that are laready seen during the fitting.

Comment: @VivekKumar Does the Kfolds function actually alter estimator/any of the model or just provide a score?

Comment: @Dave KFold just provide indices of train and test data. `cross_val_score` clones the estimator, train that cloned copy on the training data from each fold and provide score from them. So it does not alter the main estimator (which is sent into it) in any way.

Comment: @VivekKumar Thanks Vivek. So, how can we use KFolds to train our ANN model or is it's only function as a score. Would you use this or any other method of cross validation?

Comment: @ChangfuLi 's question seems pertinent to me. How does making the estimator see the same data it did during the training, help in predicting for new data? Any resolutions to this?

Answer (score 7):

For evaluation of your system performance, you can calculate the error like following. 
You also do not need to call KFold and cross_val_score.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets, linear_model
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score, KFold
from keras.models import Sequential
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor
seed = 1

diabetes = datasets.load_diabetes()
X = diabetes.data[:150]
y = diabetes.target[:150]

def baseline_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(10, input_dim=10, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
    return model


estimator = KerasRegressor(build_fn=baseline_model, nb_epoch=100, batch_size=100, verbose=False)
estimator.fit(X, y)
prediction = estimator.predict(X)

train_error =  np.abs(y - prediction)
mean_error = np.mean(train_error)
min_error = np.min(train_error)
max_error = np.max(train_error)
std_error = np.std(train_error)
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of kerasRegressor, you can directly use model itself. 
These two snippets of the code give the exact same results:

```
estimator = KerasRegressor(build_fn=baseline_model)
estimator.fit(X, y, nb_epoch=100, batch_size=100, verbose=False, shuffle=False)
prediction = estimator.predict(X)


model = baseline_model()
model.fit(X, y, nb_epoch=100, batch_size=100, verbose=False, shuffle=False)
prediction = model.predict(X)
```

Please note that the shuffle argument of fit() function for both kerasRegressor and model needs to be False. Moreover, for having the fixed initial state and obtain reproducible results, you need to add these lines of code at the beginning of your script:

```
session = K.get_session()
init_op = tf.group(tf.tables_initializer(),tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.local_variables_initializer())
session.run(init_op)
np.random.seed(1)
tf.set_random_seed(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

you should train model on X_train and y_train
you can not train model on X and y unless you should have extra data for testing

train should be in Train
then test/predict should be on X_test.